# Problems calling two functions at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have problems when a I call a function that calls the other function that keep calling back until a puzzle is solved or find no moves.

The thing is that I need to call a function twice but with different values.

I tried storing the values, but as soon as I call the second function wchich calls back, it overrides the values.

the most important pieces of code are here:

```
function splitways(){
    var strsp,aa=dir,bb=xy;
    if(nextRock()){
        if(xy!=start){
            strsp=(aa+""+bb+""+dir+""+xy)*1;
            if(!(strsp in arr)){
                arr[strsp]=strsp;
                caller(dir,xy);
            }
        }else{
            count++;
        }
    }
}

function caller(num,pos){
    var aa=num,bb=pos;
    splitways();
    //--
    dir=aa;
    xy=bb;
    //--
    dir==1?dir=4:dir--;
    splitways();
}
```

Notes, `splitways()` changes the values of `dir` and `xy`, that is why I tried to change them back and then modifing them before the second call to `splitways()`. But with the first call everything is erased.

I tried everything I can for 2 hours... The best shot I had was to cache them on `var aa=num,bb=pos;` but that didn't work.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: don't worry about the globals `dir, xy, start, arr, etc etc...` they are intended

Comment: @Joseph no, I took meassures for that. If you are interested on the full code, see http://jsfiddle.net/WgBpJ/

Comment: the problem is the globals themselves. globals are so volatile here, editable everywhere, that you can't keep track who changed what.

Comment: @Joseph I think they are not the problem, I am sure I can reproduce the problem without globals. The problem is that these functions call themselves exponentially and I think they are running like 50 at a time

Comment: Its not multithreaded unless you have multiple events/hooks calling "splitways()" or "caller()", which you don't according to that jsfiddle link.  See my "answer" below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with your code, I think you have some of your logic mixed up:

On the first call (I assume you are calling splitways() first), you set "aa=dir" (lets only pay attention to this).  When "caller()", it takes the global variable "dir", obviously.  Now, in "caller()", you set "aa=num" which translates to "aa=dir".  You call splitways again, which then does the exact same thing: "aa=dir".  This continues constantly (AKA: until caller() is stopped being called).  However, as it goes back through the execution stack, you have, in "caller()", "dir=aa".  Now, you already did "aa=num", so "dir=aa" does absolutely nothing since you haven't changed the value of "dir" anywhere that has executed yet.

Eventually, the LATEST "caller()" call will execute the "dir==1?dir=4:dir--" line, but when that function finishes and the execution returns to the SECOND TO LAST "caller()" call, it resets "dir=aa", so dir is never actually changed until the VERY last call (the first "caller()" execution that happened).

If that made absolutely no sense, good.  There has got to be a better way for you to do what you are trying to do.  Maybe I can help with that?